# Detecting current directory in bash script

Tags: git, bash, path, git-submodules, githooks

I am attempting to write a script that initializes my git hooks differently whether my git repo is a submodule or just a regular repository. It currently looks like this:

```
# Get to root directory of client repository
if [[ ":$PATH:" != *":.git/modules:"* ]]; then # Presumed not being used as a submodule
  cd ../../
else
  cd .. # cd into .git/modules/<nameOfSubmodule> (up one level from hooks)
  submoduleName=${PWD##*/} # Get submodule name from current directory
  cd ../../../$submoduleName  
fi
```

However in testing it seems to always take the `else` route even when I am in a submodule.

Is there something I am missing in this line for determining whether my path contains the expected characters?

> if [[ ":$PATH:" != *":.git/modules:"* ]]

Comment: Are you confusing `$PATH` and `$PWD`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ "`pwd`" =~ \.git/modules ]]
```

Backticks means to run the command and get its output, `pwd` is the command that prints the current directory; mnemonic: print working directory'; `=~` is a match operator. Or simply use `$PWD`:

```
if [[ "$PWD" =~ \.git/modules ]]
```

Comment: ``$(command substitution)`` is preferred over ` `backticks` ` (consider nesting, readability). Also, no need to invoke external command ``pwd``, when you can use ``$PWD``.

Comment: Oh, and your regex is wrong (it should be ``\.git/modules$``).

Comment: `$()` is a bashism which I usually avoid. But you're right about `\.`

Comment: ``$()`` is [POSIX compatible](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03), *not bashism*.

Comment: `[[ foo =~ bar ]]` is a bashism.  Bash comparisons use the double-square-bracket notation and support regex matches.  POSIX does not support regex matches.

Comment: [There are shells](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh/sh.1.html) that only understand backticks. And of course I avoid `[[ ]]` and only use it in bash scripts in which I use explicit shebang `#! /usr/bin/env bash`.

Comment: I've been beaten up on this site regarding `$(…)` vs backticks too.  It turns out that those are all non-POSIX-compliant and all really old Unix implementations.  Hopefully very very few of those are still lingering around.  The `=~` part is definitely a bashism though.

Answer (score 0):

This uses POSIX parameter expansion (explained below) to determine if the current path ends in `/.git/modules`:

```
if [ "$PWD" != "${PWD%/.git/modules}" ]
```

More on Parameter Expansion (pasted from [`dash(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dash.1.html)):

```
 ${parameter%word}     Remove Smallest Suffix Pattern.  The word is expanded
                       to produce a pattern.  The parameter expansion then
                       results in parameter, with the smallest portion of the
                       suffix matched by the pattern deleted.
```

So e.g.

```
FOO="abcdefgabc"
echo "${FOO%bc}"    # "abcdefga"
```